# Pairing process for writeable characteristic won't start

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to set up a secure connection between a central and a peripheral in order to write to a characteristic. The value contains sensitive data so it should be encrypted.

Based on what I've read the peripheral should refuse a request and return an "Insufficient authentication" error code to initiate the pairing process, and the way to do that is by configuring the characteristic's permissions in the right way, as explained here: [iOS Core Bluetooth Not asking for Pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969570/ios-core-bluetooth-not-asking-for-pair).

However I can't figure out the correct configuration. This is the configuration I'm currently using

```
[[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"443144D7-88A6-477A-9D64-5812BCD6702A"]
                                   properties: CBCharacteristicPropertyAuthenticatedSignedWrites value:nil
                                   permissions:CBAttributePermissionsWriteable | CBAttributePermissionsWriteEncryptionRequired];
```

On the central this leads to the following error when trying to write to the characteristic, and it does not trigger the pairing process.

```
Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=0 "Unknown error." UserInfo=0x15e48110 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown error.}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite` to your characteristic's properties?

Comment: I've tried that. When I add that the data is just sent without pairing first.

Comment: If your peripheral is another iOS device that is linked to the same iCloud account then they are already paired and you won't get a pairing prompt - it drove me crazy until I figured this out.

Comment: Thanks! That's good to know. Is there an easy way to verify that the connection is encrypted that you know of?

Comment: You can check the properties for encryption required - if that is set and you are communicating then it is encrypted.  If you run your app on a device that has a different iCloud account then you should get the pairing prompt - This is what I did after banging my head against the wall for an hour - used my daughter's iPad and the pairing dialog came up straight away