# forgot device from settings shows pair popup again

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am having an app where if the blueooth device is connected, user need to forget device from settings. Now the problem is when user forget bluetooth device from settings, after going in app it shows pairing popup automatically. Is there any way to avoid this popup.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582261/ios-bluetooth-pair-now-popup) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there is no way to avoid that popup. It should be provided by iOS automatically.

Comment: So everytime when user forgets device it will show automatically?

Comment: Yes but maybe in this link you can find something that helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582261/ios-bluetooth-pair-now-popup or in the apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH5-SW7