# iOS10 Core Bluetooth returns ERROR "Authentication is insufficient" for write request

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

My iOS application receives "Authentication is insufficient" ERROR for write request when the procedure involve pairing.

iOS(Core Bluetooth) returns the ERROR if its OS version is 10 or more.
Until iOS 9.3.5, iOS returns success response(no ERROR) for the same write request.

[Steps to Reproduce]

1. Forget Pairing information in both iOS device(iOS10 or over) and
   peripheral device.
2. Launch my application and establish BLE
   connection to the peripheral device.
3. Request to write value to the
   peripheral device.
4. Allow pairing on peripheral device. Then
   Bluetooth pairing dialog shows on iOS device.
5. Wait for a few seconds(3 sec. or more ) and tap "pair" button on the dialog in step [4.]
6. From iOS(Core Bluetooth), my application receive ERROR response(Authentication is insufficient) for the write request in
   step [5.]

Does anyone face the same problem ?
I'd appreciate it if you would know the casue and/or resolution for it.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. You issue the write request (step 3) before pairing (step 4)? That has to fail if authentication is needed.

Comment: @Nebr In __CoreBluetooth__, for application, there's no way to know pairing is done or not yet. And pairing sequence is running between iOS and peripheral device, iOS application cannot touch on the procedure. iOS application just call write request, after that pairing sequence runs between iOS and peripheral if it's needed.

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969570/ios-core-bluetooth-not-asking-for-pair

Comment: @Nebr Thank you for your information. But in my case, pairing is OK, actually pairing is executed between peripheral device and iOS, and iOS application can not detect the status such as "pairing is running". And in my case, pairing dialog is shown by system, it's OK.

Comment: Check https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20585 for details